# React not rendering component when changing routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a page with products. My problem is that when I try to click on a product, the url is changing, but nothing renders on the screen. It still shows the component where all the products are rendered.

I tried couple of different things, but nothing seemed to work

```
<Route path="store" element={<Store />}>
  <Route path="protein" element={<Products />} />
  <Route path="protein/*" element={<SingleProduct />} />
</Route>
```

I also tried with:

```
<Route path="store" element={<Store />}>
  <Route path="protein" element={<Products />}>
    <Route path="*" element={<SingleProduct />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Also with:

```
<Route path="/store/protein/*" element={<SingleProduct />} />
```

So that it is not a child route.

But that also didn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: That is my Store component :

```
import React from "react";
import SidePanel from "../components/storeComponents/SidePanel";
import Products from "../components/storeComponents/Products";
import "./Store.css";

const Store = () => {
  return (
    <div className="store-page">
      <SidePanel />
      <Products />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Store;
```

Comment: may be try somethign like this

<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        
        {/* The catch-all route */}
        <Route component={NotFound} />

Comment: You are rendering `Products` and `SingleProduct` on the same route path. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, especially the three UI components in the routes.

Comment: @BinitGhetiya That syntax is for an older React-Router version. OP is using v6 based on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing path [splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats) are used when the routed component is rendering ***descendent*** routes, e.g. if `SingleProduct` rendered another `Routes` and set of `Route` components, the trailing `"*"` allows these routes to also be matched. You are trying to use ***nested*** routes though.

The `Store` component is just rendering the `Products` component directly. It should instead render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render out their content.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Store = () => {
  return (
    <div className="store-page">
      <SidePanel />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You are also rendering `Products` and `SingleProduct` on the same route path. You likely want to render `SingleProduct` on a sub-route path with a dynamic path segment, e.g. something like `"protein/:productId"`.

```
<Route path="store" element={<Store />}>
  <Route path="protein" element={<Products />} />
  <Route path="protein/:productId" element={<SingleProduct />} />
</Route>
```

Ensure that the `Products` component is correctly linking to a valid `"/store/protein/:productId"` path. Examples:

Absolute path from root `"/"`:

```
<Link to={`/store/protein/${product.id}`}>
  {product.title}
</Link>
```

Relative path from products page `"/store/protein"`:

```
<Link to={product.id}> // <-- no leading slash "/" character
  {product.title}
</Link>
```